# Securing a very, very old 220V switch

Tags: safety, plug, appliances

We recently acquired a very old saw that accepts either 220V or 120V.

It came with a suicide (male-male) cord, in turn going to a female-socket cable:

[image: female plug]

which in turn goes to a DPST switch:

[image: dpst]

in turn going to the motor assembly. The motor details are difficult to photograph:

[image: motor]

[image: wiring]

This thing is somewhat of a death trap. The spades on the switch have already shorted together once and tripped a breaker. The switch is probably dual-pole because it supports 240V, but we are only ever going to run it single-phase 120V. In my imagination, to make this thing safer, I would:

- Disconnect the neutrals from the switch, short them to each other and cover the connection with heat shrink
- Unscrew the suicide cord plug and swap genders so that the male plug is appliance-side and the female socket is wall-side
- Add more heat shrink around the live spades on the switch to insulate them and prevent them from shorting out

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: I see but do not understand the close vote. I am not asking about how to use this appliance; I'm going to be modifying its wiring.

Comment: Many people are careless about selecting reasons for close votes because they are not satisfied with the list of choices. Questions about repairing or modifying products are usually closed if they don't involve electrical design or theory and or the asker does not seem well equipped to solve the problem. Are you assuming that the switch selects either 120 or 240 V operation? Have you operated the saw or seen it in operation? If it needs a neutral for 240 V operation, part of it must need 120 V when operating on 240 V.

Comment: @CharlesCowie _Are you assuming that the switch selects either 120 or 240 V operation?_ - No; it turns the device on or off. _Have you operated the saw or seen it in operation?_ - Yes, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condgratulations, you are now the owner of a finger eating machine, the saw table is the main reason why so many old carpenters have fewer than 10 fingers. But being motivated to make this purchase probably know that already.

I would seriously consider replacing that rocker switch with a proper emergency stop button. you could probably convert that rocker switch by putting a hinged panel in front of it with a hole for "on" and the whole panel for off.

You should definately replace those spade connectors with insulated spade connectors, your plan of using using heatshrink to upgrade them
to insulated is a good way to do that.

Mount the switch to a proper panel, I don't see a mounting panel, but perhaps you removed it to take the photo.

if you disconnect the neutrals from the switch use a male-male spade joiner, or a proper splice connector to join them together.

Comment: Correct, I removed the panel for the photo but will be reinstalling it.

Comment: Confirmed - shorting neutrals together and swapping cord genders has not harmed the operation, and no more tripped breakers.